# Led on for one minute eve if the switch is pressed for more than one minute?

Tags: transistors, led, switches, timer

how to make a circuit that when press the switch the led is gonna stay on for one minute and than off even if the switch is still pressed for more than one minute

Comment: What if it is pressed quickly once or rapidly for >1 min?  Or on power up? 3 unspecified conditions.

Comment: Have you done any research on this idea? What is your electronics background...can you program a microcontroller?

Comment: @Tony EE rocketscientist----if I keep it pressed more than one minutes

Comment: Elliot Alderson ---Yeah I know how to program a microcontroller but I don`t have one....